# JMS consumer for message retrieval and listening

Tags: java, hibernate, jms

I created a standalone Java application that acts as a consumer that retrieves/listens for messages inside an ActiveMQ queue. Planning to run two instances of these on different machines for high availability purposes.

What bothers me is the usage of `Connection`, `Session`, `MessageConsumer`, and `Transaction` (Hibernate). I didn't want to open a new `Connection`, `Session`, `MessageConsumer` everytime a message is found inside the queue because there will be at least 1 message per second inside the queue and just opening/closing resources would not be very efficient (right?). With regards to closing the `Transaction` object, will that be alright? Or should I keep the transaction open as long as the application is running?

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import net.mycompany.SomeDaoObject;
import net.mycompany.SomeDomainObject;
import net.mycompany.util.HibernateUtil;
import net.mycompany.util.SomeProperties;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class Consumer implements Runnable, MessageListener{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class);
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private static Connection connection;
    private MessageConsumer consumer;
    private Session session;
    private SomeDaoObject someDaoObject = new SomeDaoObject();

    public Consumer() throws Exception {
        this.session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(SomeProperties.queueName());

        this.consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
        this.consumer.setMessageListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //Start the connection
            logger.info("Connection starting...");
            connection.start();
        }
        catch (JMSException ex){
            logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage txtMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            Transaction transaction = null;

            try {
                SomeDomainObject object= gson.fromJson(txtMessage.getText(), SomeDomainObject.class);
                object.setCreateTimestamp(new Date());
                object.setCreateUsername("CONSUMER");

                logger.info(String.format("Saving object... %s", object));

                transaction = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
                someDaoObject.save(object);
                transaction.commit();
                session.commit();

            } catch (JMSException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                try {
                    session.rollback();
                } catch (JMSException e1) {
                  logger.error(e1.getMessage(), e1);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);

                if (transaction != null)
                    transaction.rollback();
            }

            finally {
                HibernateUtil.closeCurrentSession();
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            HibernateUtil.setConnectionParameters(SomeProperties.blvdDbConnectionUrl(),
                    SomeProperties.blvdDbUsername(),
                    SomeProperties.blvdDbPassword(),
                    SomeProperties.blvdDbShowSql());
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            logger.error(e1.getMessage(), e1);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;

        try {
            connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(SomeProperties.brokerUrl());
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            new Thread(new Consumer()).start();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        addShutdownHook();
    }

    private static void addShutdownHook() {
        final Thread shutdownHook = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                logger.info("Shutting down...");

                if (connection != null) {
                    try {
                        connection.close();
                    } catch (JMSException e) {
                        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(shutdownHook);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with Hibernate, and I'm rusty at JMS, so I'll review the other parts of your code...

You have two inconsistent braces usage for your `try-catch` block:

```
try {
    // ...
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // ...
}
```

The `catch` should be on the same line as the first closing `}`.

To reduce an additional level of nesting inside your `onMessage()` method, you can invert the case for your `if` statement to return early first:

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    if (!(message instanceof TextMessage)) {
        return;
    }
    TextMessage txtMessage = (TextMessage) message;
    // ...
}
```

**More importantly**, I will suggest decoupling the lines that handle the creation of your domain objects and those that handle the Hibernate persistence. That can greatly reduce/eliminate the nested error handling you have to do in your code currently. More importantly, it makes your code easier to recover from errors. For example, if it's only the Hibernate persistence failing, you could potentially cache your non-persisted domain objects first before feeding to Hibernate again.

```
try {
    transaction = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    someDaoObject.save(object);
    transaction.commit();
    session.commit();
} catch (Exception e) { // using generic Exception for illustration only
    // ...
} finally {
    HibernateUtil.closeCurrentSession();
}
```

I think the crux of your problem really lies in how your company's (?) `HibernateUtil` class is handling the underlying database resources efficiently or not. If it's possible (legally/technically), you can optionally share the workings of `HibernateUtil` as another review question for that... In any case, if it is reasonably efficiently at [connection pooling](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch01.html), then you don't have much to worry about.

Similarly, you can also consider the same [connection pooling](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-jms-efficiently.html) techniques for your ActiveMQ usage.

```
this.session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

Do you need to consider resiliency for handling messages that failed to be persisted via Hibernate? In fact, would you need to consider the need for [Java Transaction API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API) so that you can synchronize (layman-speak) the persistence of your domain object *with* the acknowledgement of your JMS message?

Oh yeah, one last thing...

```
public Consumer() throws Exception { ... }
```

Since the body of this method will only throw `JMSException` (most of the called methods) or `InvalidDestinationException` (`session.createConsumer(Destination)`), I will suggest throwing these two specific `Exception` types rather than a generic `Exception`. First, other reviewers or developers will understand the exact nature of the possible `Exception`s that can be thrown from this method. Second, should further changes in this method yield more checked `Exception`s, you will get a compilation error first as a heads-up.

Comment: Thank you so much for this input! I have a few questions though. You said "Similarly, you can also consider the same connection pooling techniques for your ActiveMQ usage." I don't understand... can the ActiveMQ pool session objects as well? I don't really see why JMS session pooling must be done in my application since this is a single-threaded app.

Comment: @MiguelPortugal to quote from the ActiveMQ page I linked to: "The reason is that each create & destroy of the above objects typically requires an individual request & response with the JMS broker to ensure it worked. e.g. creating a connection, session, producer, then sending a message, then closing everything down again - could result in 7 request-responses with the server!" So ActiveMQ does not pool sessions natively, but they seem to recommend it, especially if you are also using an Enterprise JavaBean (EJB) container.